# How to pass a value from controller to routeprovider in angularjs

Tags: angularjs

Is it possible to pass a variable from controller to routeProvider depends on screen width?

**app.js**

```
var app = angular.module('Location', []). <br />
    config(['$routeProvider', function ($routeProvider) { <br />
      $routeProvider. <br />
        when('/', { templateUrl: 'pages/desktop/locationList.html', controller: Location }). <br />
        when('/locationDetail/:projectId', { <br />
          templateUrl: function (params) { return 'pages/desktop/locationDetail.html'; }, <br />
          controller: Location <br />
        }). <br />
        otherwise({ redirectTo: '/' }); <br />
    }]) <br /> <br />
app.config(['$locationProvider', function($location) { <br />
    $location.hashPrefix('!'); <br />
}]); <br /> <br />
```

**Controller**

```
function Location($scope, $http, $routeParams) {<br />
    $scope.projectId = $routeParams.projectId;<br />
    $scope.selectedProject = null;<br />
    $scope.locationList = null;<br />
    $scope.path = null;<br /><br />

    $http.get("location.json")<br />
        .success(function(data){<br />
            $scope.locationList  = data;<br /><br />

            var indexedloc = [];<br />
            $scope.locationListToFilter = function(){<br />
                indexedloc = [];<br />
                return $scope.locationList;   <br />       
            }<br />

            $scope.filterLocation = function(Loc){<br />
                var locationIsNew = indexedloc.indexOf(Loc.field_data_field_location_field_location) == -1;<br />
                if(locationIsNew){<br />
                    indexedloc.push(Loc.field_data_field_location_field_location)   <br />                                                                      
                }<br />
                return locationIsNew;<br />
            }              <br />
            $scope.returnFilterLoc = function(){return indexedloc};<br /><br />

            if($scope.projectId && $scope.projectId != null) {      <br />      
                for(var i = 0; i < $scope.locationList.length; i++){<br />
                    if($scope.locationList[i].tid == $scope.projectId) {<br />
                        $scope.selectedProject = $scope.locationList[i];<br />
                    }<br />
                }<br />
            }<br />

        })<br />
        .error(function(data) {<br />
            $("div.category-wrapper").html("Error");<br />
        });<br />
}<br /><br />
```

I want to change templateUrl depends on screen width. 
Thanks

Comment: I do not think you can... When using `when()`, globally, template is loaded first to the DOM and the controller is instantiate after that during compilation phase.

Answer (score 0):

it's hard to understand what you need but i can suggest you use `resolve` to call your function and take the screen width:

```
$routeProvider
    .when("/news", {
        templateUrl: "newsView.html",
        controller: "newsController",
        resolve: {
            message: function(param){
                // Your code
        }
    }
})
```

here is [some explanation](http://odetocode.com/blogs/scott/archive/2014/05/20/using-resolve-in-angularjs-routes.aspx) :

> A resolve is a property you can attach to a route in both ngRoute and
>   the more robust UI router. A resolve contains one or more promises
>   that must resolve successfully before the route will change. This
>   means you can wait for data to become available before showing a view,
>   and simplify the initialization of the model inside a controller
>   because the initial data is given to the controller instead of the
>   controller needing to go out and fetch the data.

Comment: Good idea, but I do not think you can change the templateUrl during resolving phase.